# Fix bubble plot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

I am trying to plot a `hollow` bubble plot. The plot is fine except the legend is not showing the bubble size in the `legend`. It can be seen in the legend the increment in the `bubble` is not shown in legend.

How can I fix this?

I did look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814927/ggplot2-r-how-to-fix-size-of-bubble-in-legend) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684201/custom-legend-for-bubble-plot-using-ggplot) question, but it did not fix the legend.

Code + sample data

```
library(elevatr)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(tidyverse)

# Create an example data.frame
set.seed(65.7)
examp_df = data.frame(x = runif(3, min = -73, max = -72.5), y = runif(3, min = 42,
    max = 43))
prj_dd = "EPSG:4326"

# Create and example data.frame with additional columns
cats = data.frame(category = c("H", "M", "L"))

examp_df2 = data.frame(examp_df, cats)

# Create an example SpatialPoints
examp_sp = SpatialPoints(examp_df, proj4string = CRS(prj_dd))

    # Create an example SpatialPointsDataFrame
    examp_spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(examp_sp, data = cats)
    # Get elevation data
    spdf_elev_epqs = get_elev_point(examp_spdf, src = "epqs")
    # Convert to sf object
    examp_sfdf = st_as_sf(spdf_elev_epqs)
    # Plot
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data = examp_sfdf, aes(size = elevation ), shape = 1, show.legend = T) +
      coord_sf() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
          labs( size = "Mean Elevation (meters)")
```

Plot

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick, done, please check.

Comment: @MrFlick, please note that that I used the `elevatr` package to get the sample `DEM` values.

Comment: My legend works after running your example: The bubbles have different sizes. (R 4.1.0)

Comment: @danlooo, this is strange, did you modify the code in the question or did you run the exact code?

Comment: I did an exact rerun of the code you provided on a fresh environment.

Comment: @danlooo, wow, could this be a glitch in `RStudio` then? Should I restart the studio?

Comment: This must be due to R itself. RStudio is just the IDE. If a session restart did not work, you can try isolated fresh docker images (I used `rocker/verse:4.1.0`)

Comment: @danlooo, turns out not running `set.seed(65.7)` was causing the issue. I don't know how `set.seed` relates to plotting a correct `ggplot` bubble legend! Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You probably cleaned the environment just when you incorporated the seed

Comment: @danlooo, yes, you are absolutely right, and it turns out as soon I start storing variables in the environment, the legend problem returns back. I don't know what's really going on here.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the packages you are using: Some things might not be properly isolated from the global environment.

Comment: @danlooo, is there a work around this instead of restarting the session every time? I am actually not familiar with `docker` on `Windows 10`.

Comment: It is called docker desktop on win10. If you have wsl2, you can also just use the Linux subsystem so you can just install the docker engine directly

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Newer versions of the question involves only one size scale.

It seems that the aesthetic `size` is used in both the rectangle and in the circle geom. `ggplot2` merges the axes by default and only shows one of them. You can use the R package `ggnewscale` to explicitly have multiple size scales.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)

diamonds %>%
  head() %>%
  ggplot(aes(cut, color)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = x), shape = 1, color = "red") +
    scale_size(limits = c(0, 10)) +
    new_scale(new_aes = "size") +
    geom_point(aes(size = y), shape = 1, color = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you but when I use the `scale_size` and `new_scale` arguments in the above code, I get this error `Error in check.length(gparname) : 
  'gpar' element 'fontsize' must not be length 0`. Also in my case I only have one `size` argument.

Comment: your new example has only one size scale thus you do not need `new_scale` anymore